# Redirect Loop During Login with Implicit Flow in OpenId Connect Middleware

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, openid-connect, identityserver3

On server I have Identity Server 3 Identity Server. On client side, I have UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication. This is working great. But suddenly after some times when user successfully logged in at my identity server, the redirection starts looping until I get error maximum request size for everyone using the client application. Then I re-start the pool of client application, everything become working again. Is there some caching stuff in OpenIdConnectAuthentication middleware that has this result? This affects just the client app.

Comment: Give some code (client configuration, server configuration). For me, it sounds like some of your RedirectUri's are wrong, but can't be sure without some code

Comment: @m3n7alsnak3 I am saying everything work expected when I restart the pool but then after few hours it start redirecting.

Comment: Do you have logging enabled? What does tho log say when the thing starts to occur?

Comment: Are you talking about log at server or client? Is there is way to enable logging for OpenIdConnectAuthentication?

Comment: I'm talking about identity server logging.

Comment: Currently this issue is not happening, I will add logs and check when it happens. Thanks